# Merge [bugcheck] into [bsod]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

[bugcheck](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bugcheck) contains 16 questions, practically all of which are about [bsod](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bsod). "[Bugcheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" is the technical term for a BSOD and so the tags should be merged.

Your thoughts?

Comment: I'm all in for it.

Comment: Bizarre trademark dispute? Ridiculous! On topic - I think the bugcheck questions should perhaps be under bsod, but bugcheck *shouldn't* be a synonym for bsod, as that's Windows only.

Comment: @terdon: ["When Microsoft Windows encounters a condition that compromises safe system operation, the system halts. This condition is called a *bug check*. It is also commonly referred to as a *system crash*, a *kernel error*, a *Stop error*, or *BSOD*."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen ah so I was missing something, thanks.

Comment: Unsure why some people downvoted this, `bugcheck` may not _sound_ like the same thing as `bsod` but as @IlmariKaronen pointed out, the terms are synonymous!

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, someone that tags a *nix (or OSX?) question with "bugcheck" should instead be using "kernel-panic"?

Comment: I'd say that both should be removed. The terms are far too general and I just can't see why anyone would be looking through either group of questions specifically. Look at the other synonyms you gave. Would `system-crash` be a valuable tag? While you're at it, get rid of `kernel-panic` for the same reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bugcheck](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bugcheck) has been merged with [bsod](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bsod) and a synonym has been created.

Answer (score 6):

TLDR: burninate [bugcheck](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bugcheck), retag to [bsod](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bsod)

---

Being a WinDbg user (see my profile on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480982/thomas-weller?tab=profile)), I totally agree that these are synonyms.

As [Ilmari Karonen](https://meta.superuser.com/users/99516/ilmari-karonen) pointed out already, this is defined on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> When Microsoft Windows encounters a condition that compromises safe system operation, the system halts. This condition is called a bug check. It is also commonly referred to as a system crash, a kernel error, a Stop error, or BSOD. A hardware device, its driver, or related software might have caused this error.

I don't agree to the statement

> I'd say that both should be removed. The terms are far too general and I just can't see why anyone would be looking through either group of questions specifically.

because there are people like me who are interested in answering such questions, independent of other tags like programming languages etc.

At the same time, it's reasonable to have separate tags for Windows and Linux, because

1. the terms are different and nobody would use an even more general term such as `system-crash` and
2. analyzing a [bsod](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bsod) on Windows with WinDbg is very different from analyzing a [kernel-panic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kernel-panic) with GDB on Linux. Many people will only be familiar with one OS, so they should be able to follow only the relevant ones.

When I talk to people, I have never heard them use the term [bugcheck](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bugcheck). Considering 16 questions against 1042 BSOD questions, this seems to be the case for others as well.

Conclusion: burninate [bugcheck](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bugcheck), retag to [bsod](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bsod).